# rails::offline in routes.rb throws undefined method `offline' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying enable offline mode for my Rails apps by following the Offline Apps Railcast in the below URL

http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1

Made the following changes to my app

- Added gem 'rack-offline' to gemfile
- Added match "/application.manifest" => Rails::offline to routes.rb
- Updated HTML tag to  in application.html.erb
- Added ENV["RAILS_ASSET_ID"] = "" to application.rb

When trying to start rails server it throws the following error

undefined method `offline' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
Rails::Offline
```